# Format date from: 01/01/2017 to 1/1/2017

Tags: visualforce, formatting

Got this code:

```
<apex:outputText value=" {0,date,MM/dd/yyyy }"> <apex:param value="{!IF(Lead.CreatedDate!=null,Lead.CreatedDate+90,'N/A')}"/></apex:outputtext>
```

how to format date from: 01/01/2017 to 1/1/2017?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change:

```
MM/dd/yyyy
```

to:

```
M/d/yyyy
```